# Get http url path of local file on server in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using ASP.NET with MVC 2 and have trouble translating a local file url to a server address. It would seem like a fairly simple and common task, but google searches gives me no good answers. (Perhaps i suck at searching)

I have a controller that takes a file from a html form in a view and saves it to disk. I need to return the real url of this file back to the View. Whatever method i use, I always get a string with the local path of the file instead of the http path.

I suspect the url might get translated to http address once the project has been deployed, but I really need the server address when debugging without having to hardcode anything.

Consider the following example in some controller method:

```
string url = Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Files/" + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
// outputs: "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\[ProjectName]\\Content\\Files\\file.png"
// whereas i'd like something like "http://localhost/Content/Files/file.png" instead
```

any ideas?

Comment: `Server.MapPath` maps a URL to a local file, returning the local file. Don't use it.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on where you are storing this file. If you are storing it in a directory which is outside of the virtual directory root you won't be able to access it. If the file is inside a folder which is accessible over HTTP you could simply use the [Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx) method:

```
string url = Url.Content("~/Content/Files/foo.txt");
```

Comment: I'm storing the file to the Content/Files folder. I'd rather be able to return the url of the file instead of using Url.Content in my view. The reason for this is that i want to further work with the url in javascript. (convert the url to [BB] code which is then inserted in a textbox for a chat application i'm working on)

Comment: You could use Url.Content in your controller. Url is a property of the controller.

Comment: using Url.Content in my controller as you suggest, how can I get the base url for the server? ie: http://localhost/theApp?

Comment: string file_url = Request.Url.Authority + Url.Content("~/Content/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

would solve my initial question. Thanks guys! :)